# Team Viewer can't run applications in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, teamviewer

I'm trying to use **TeamViewer 8** from a **Windows 7** computer to access a **Windows 8** computer, and I'm having a strange problem.

The scenario is the following:

1. The connection is fine and I can access the remote computer.
2. I can *explore* Windows in the remote computer, I mean, I can open File Explorer, Internet Explorer, Control Panel, etc.
3. However, when I try to run any other application in the remote computer that doesn't *belong* to Windows, I can still view the remote screen, but I can't control the remote computer, I mean, I can't even control de mouse...
4. If then the user of the remote PC closes the application, I have the control of the remote PC again...

Do you know why this is happening?

I've been using TeamViewer from Windows 7 to Windows 7 without problem, so I guess is something about Windows 8, but I don't know what... The teamviewer website says that it's compatible with Windows 8...

---

*EDIT: and in the case nobody knows the solution, can you suggest any other good application for remote control that works well in Windows 8?*

Comment: ask this the teamveiwer support

Comment: "Remote destop" is in my opinion the fastest but not suitable for remote support (i.e. both sides can view the screen) and you'll need a vpn to set it up securely. You could try logmein.com or even google chrome remote control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved in recent updates of TeamViewer

Answer (score 0):

change your team viewer mode and switch it win xp in compatability mode.... by going into properties of TV and select comaptibility mode as win xp in remote computer